# Validation errors message on array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Quoting [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#validating-arrays):

> Likewise, you may use the * character when specifying your validation messages in your language files, making it a breeze to use a single validation message for array based fields:
>
> `'custom' => ['person.*.email' => ['unique' => 'Each person must have a unique e-mail address']]`

It seems it does not work. I have a validation message:

```
'infos.*.*.*' => ['required' => 'My text']
```

Then I have some inputs in my view:

```
<input type="text" name="infos[1234][0][name]">
<input type="text" name="infos[1234][1][name]">
<input type="text" name="infos[5678][0][name]">
```

And in my controller I validate the input:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'infos.*.*.*' => 'required'
]);
```

And in view I have a error displayer:

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <strong>Oops. Errors:</strong>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

And if I leave all input empty I got:

```
My text
My text
My text
My text
My text
etc.
```

What's wrong with my code? Reading Laravel documentation I though it should have worked (I mean: it should have been displayed only once). Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: `$this->validate($request, [
    'infos.*.*.name' => 'required'
]);`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Ok my example was simplified. I have some inputs with `name` and some other with `email`. And I want to use them all with the same validator

Comment: It's working as intended. If you send 3 input in the array which fails, you'd getting 3 error messages, one for each failed validation.

Comment: @Sandeesh Ok so maybe I misunderstood the documentation when I read "making it a breeze to use a single validation message for array based fields". You can post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as intended. Since you're passing multiple inputs in an array, the validation throws an error for each item. Therefore 3 inputs with 2 causing errors and 1 passing would obviously pass error for 2 inputs. So in your case the multiple errors are due to multiple inputs failing validation.